# Index by MultIIndex level name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I am writing some functions that I want to be generic, so I'm looking to allow them to accept level keys (like groupby does).  So that they can continue to do what they do even if the MultiIndex structure changes slightly.

Suppose that you are given the level Name, how would you slice into that particular level.  I want to index using the parameter of `xs`, by the name of those levels but to be able to set into the resulting slice.

I want to do a mixture of the following:

```
df.xs('a0', axis, 'lvla') = OTHER_OBJECT #except you can't set into xs
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['a0',:,:,:],:] = OTHER_OBJECT #except you only know the level name
```

Below is something that will create a large MultiIndex  to play with.  (Copied and slightly modified from Pandas documentation)

```
def mklbl(prefix,n):
    return ["%s%s" % (prefix,i)  for i in range(n)]

miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A',4),
                                      mklbl('B',2),
                                      mklbl('C',4),
                                      mklbl('D',2)],
                                     names=['lvlA', 'lvlB', 'lvlC', 'lvlD'])

micolumns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a','foo'),('a','bar'),
                                       ('b','foo'),('b','bah')],
                                       names=['lvl0', 'lvl1'])


dfmi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(miindex)*len(micolumns)).reshape((len(miindex),len(micolumns))),
                   index=miindex,
                   columns=micolumns).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of an output you'd like to see?

Comment: i want o be able to do something like: `df.loc("lvlA")["a0"]` without knowing which level number `"lvlA"` is. This can be done with `xs` function, but I would like to SET into the cross section